# How to use the color of an alert block for a ruler?

Tags: beamer, color, vertical-alignment, positioning, block

I have a beamer presentation and an alert block. I want to insert a *horizontal ruler* to seperate text. To fit into the style of the presentation, it should match the color of the surrounding alert block. How can I use the color of the alert blocks title line? At the moment I am just using a color that matched okay-ish in my opinion.

```
\begin{center}
    \textcolor{BrickRed}{\hrulefill}
\end{center}
```

I am aware of the command `\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure} text`, but I do not know what to put for `fg` and `structure` to give be the desired color (yes, I checked the beamer documentation).

### [image]

**Extra**: At the moment, the exact vertical positioning of the `\hrulefill` is achieved by two (annoyingly fine-tuned) `\vspace`-commands, one before and one after the ruler. Without these, there are *huge* gaps between the text and the ruler. Is there a better way to achieve a nice positioning?

---

**Update**

The problem with the color seems to be solved by the answer of *samcarter*. For the positioning problem I was pointed out to provide an MWE:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}

\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frenet equations}

\begin{alertblock}{\textbf{Theorem:} Frenet equations}
    For the Frenet frame $(\bf t,\bf n)$ of a curve holds
    \begin{align*}
        \bf t'(t) &= \phantom+\kappa(t)\bf n(t),\\
        \bf n'(t) &= -\kappa(t)\bf t(t).
    \end{align*}
    %
    \vspace{-3em}
    \begin{center}
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{block title alerted}\hrulefill
    \end{center}
    %
    \vspace{-0.5em}
    The equations can be written in \emph{matrix form}:
    $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \bf t'\\\bf n'
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        \phantom-0&\kappa\\-\kappa&0
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        \bf t\\\bf n
        \end{pmatrix}.
    $$
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `{\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\hrulefill}`

Comment: @JasperHabicht I know, I just wonder what to use for `structure` and `fg`. Any idea?

Comment: Just use `structure` and `fg`. This will select the appropriate color.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Ah I see. Unfortunately the ruler becomes blue (color of the normal block I guess). I tried `alert structure` and `alert block structure` and `structure alert` but nothing worked.

Comment: Maybe `block title` and `bg`? Which theme do you use? If you post a MWE, it is much easier to help. ;)

Comment: If you want help with the vertical spacing, please include a MWE.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347269/different-colors-for-different-types-of-blocks-in-beamer

Comment: @samcarter Added a MWE. Thanks for the solution with the colors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the colour with `\usebeamercolor[bg]{block title alerted}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{alertblock}{block title}
        content...
    \end{alertblock}

    {\usebeamercolor[bg]{block title alerted}\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

---

The large vertical spacing mainly comes from the `center` environment, which is not necessary anyway for an element which spans the whole line.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}

\usetheme{Malmoe}  %% Themenwahl
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frenet equations}

\begin{alertblock}{\textbf{Theorem:} Frenet equations}
    For the Frenet frame $(\bf t,\bf n)$ of a curve holds
    \begin{align*}
        \bf t'(t) &= \phantom+\kappa(t)\bf n(t),\\
        \bf n'(t) &= -\kappa(t)\bf t(t).
    \end{align*}%

    \vspace{-1em}
    {\usebeamercolor[bg]{block title alerted}\hrulefill}

    The equations can be written in \emph{matrix form}:
    \[\begin{pmatrix}
    \bf t'\\\bf n'
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    \phantom-0&\kappa\\-\kappa&0
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    \bf t\\\bf n
    \end{pmatrix}.\]
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, the center-environment was a leftover from when I used the `\rule` which was not as long as the block. However, why is there still such an insame amount of space below the first formula which I have to compensate with the `\vspace{-1em}`?

Comment: @M.Winter The space is not insane, it is the normal space after an align environment. The distance to a normal text line is the same, it just appears smaller as normal letters accent from their baseline and fill part of the space. Replace the rule with `_ _ _ _ _ _ ` and you'll see that is the same space. To compensate this different appearance, the `\vspace{-1em}` reduce the space by approximately the height of normal letters.

Comment: I see. I somehow imagined the ruler to be in the center of the line and not on the baseline. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

One simple hack is to redefine the Beamer block color into BrickRed, using

`\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=BrickRed,fg=black}`

I've put together a simple example showcasing the effect, with a little help from [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33231/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-block-within-a-custom-beamer-sty-theme-file).

[image]

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=BrickRed,fg=black}

\makeatletter
   \def\vhrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\hfill \kern\z@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Theorem}
    \begin{center}
    some text

    \textcolor{BrickRed}{\vhrulefill{6pt}}

    some more text
    \end{center}    
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```