# Defining beamer block with customizable colors

Tags: beamer, color, block

I am trying to define a block with customizable colors. I want to put this in a file of common definitions (say `common_defs.tex`) and include it in each presentation and set its title and text background and foreground colors based on the theme of that presentation. Using the suggestion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33231/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-block-within-a-custom-beamer-sty-theme-file) I define the following in the `common_defs.tex` file

```
\newenvironment{varblock}[3]{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{#2}
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{#3}
  \begin{block}{#1}}{\end{block}}
```

Now in the main beamer presentation I have the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{varblock text}{bg=red!20, fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{varblock title}{bg=red, fg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Test}

\begin{varblock}{Block Title}
Some block text
\end{varblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This, understandably gives an error since it expects three arguments to \begin{varblock}. How can I change the definition to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will this work?

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\input{common}    
\newcommand{\prevarblock}{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=red!20, fg=black}%
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=red, fg=white}%
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
    \begin{varblock}{Block Title}
      Some block text
    \end{varblock}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**common.tex**

```
\newenvironment{varblock}[1]{%
  \prevarblock
  \begin{block}{#1}}{\end{block}}
```

Comment: Perfect -- many thanks. Worked like a charm. Learn something new every day.